# How to run podman from within a kubernetes pod

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, podman

We are using Jenkins for the CI/CD solution and all are code run within the kubernetes pods using the jenkins agent image. We have upgraded to kubernetes 1.20 version which doesnt use daemon. So, as an alternative we are using podman. Our k8s pod runs with a user 'abc'. Within the jenkins agent image which is used to spin the agent pod, we have installed podman and the agent pod runs on a Linux 7.9 VM.
On the Linux VM, we have set the uid and gid

```
[xyz@oke-cdrnkbr37bq-nk4yoht2oja-svxwfrwpi5q-0 ~]$ cat /etc/subuid
xyz:100000:65536
abc:165536:65536
[xyz@oke-cdrnkbr37bq-nk4yoht2oja-svxwfrwpi5q-0 ~]$ cat /etc/subgid
xyz:100000:65536
zbc:165536:65536
```

Now, when the pod is spinned up in Jenkins, we are not seeing the uid mapping within the pod -

```
bash$ k exec -it pod-template-agent-d0tzf -n jenkins-ns -- bash
bash-4.4$ cat /proc/self/uid_map  
         0          0 4294967295
```

Due to this if I try to execute the podman commands within the k8s pod, I keep getting the following error -

```
bash-4.4$ podman run fedora cat /proc/self/uid_map 
Error: OCI runtime error: rootless container requires user namespaces
```

Any ideas how to resolve this user namespace error and get the podman working?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how exactly did you set up your cluster? Which Kubernetes solution are you using - some bare-metal or cloud provider?

Comment: Check if there should be 'zbc' in /etc/subgid

Comment: We are using Oracle cloud provider to setup the kubernetes cluster. On the VM where the jenkins pod runs, I have ensured that the user entry is there in subuid and subgid files. When I login to the k8s pod, I cant find that mapping within the pod.

Comment: You have 'abc' in /etc/subuid, but 'zbc' in /etc/subgid. Please check if this is on purpose or a typo.

Comment: check this https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-inside-kubernetes, and show more how the pod-template yaml file is written, it depends on your cloud env as well

Answer (score 0):

I recently created [Podman Jenkins agent](https://www.rokpoto.com/podman-jenkins-agent/) docker image. In the linked post, you can also see a demo of Jenkins using Podman Jenkins agent as a Kubernetes pod.